# SSAS Cubes Discovery Method for DSV to establish relationship between dimension and source view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssas, mdx, cubes

I come across project where I need to establish connections between SSAS cubes dimensions and their views in DW , I was trying to use discovery method :

```
call assp.DiscoverXmlMetadata("\Database\DataSourceViews\DataSourceView\Schema\xs:schema\xs:element\xs:complexType\xs:choice\xs:element")
```

- This gives me only names of views in my DataWarehouse

Below is giving me dimensions details but without any reference to DSV objects:

```
call assp.DiscoverXmlMetadata("\Database\Dimensions\Dimension|Name\Attributes\Attribute|Name,Usage\AttributeRelationships\AttributeRelationship")
```

How I can obtain any relationship between Dimension and View - they must exist somewhere in cube XML's .
Also , I dont think the $system.MDSchema*... holds any of the references  from DSV - Or is just me ?
Any help or suggestion really appreciated.

Comment: Try the following MDX query it should help.
select * from $System.DBSCHEMA_TABLES

Comment: I was trying that already and this do not contain any references to the source tables in DW - it refers only to top references in DSV.
There must be a way to get that from XMLA files  but so far I have no success :(